# Updating model variable upon navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why isn't `{{ username }}` variable (in example below) updated when I'm navigating using in-page links? The variable is only set on initial page load (equal to Anonymous) and isn't updated no more, why is that? Code i plain and simple (http://jsbin.com/OTApeYI/1/):

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="examp">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js">    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
    <a href="#">Home</a>, <a href="Admin">Admin</a>

    Your user name is: {{ username }}

    <script>
angular.module('examp', ['examp.controllers']).
  config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when('/:username', {controller: 'ExampleCtrl'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
  });

angular.module('examp.controllers', [])
  .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.username = $routeParams.username ? $routeParams.username : "Anonymous";
  }]);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting a new instance of the controller when you open a new route? I think this may be the problem, if it's still the same instance of the controller that would explain why $scope.username is not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you need the `ngView` directive to activate routing.  Second, `ExampleCtrl` is only created once and you are setting `$scope.username` to the current value at that time.  `$routeParams.username` is a simple string, you might as well set `$scope.username = ''`  You can however store the `$routeParams` object on your scope and bind to the `username` property [(SAMPLE)](http://jsbin.com/OTApeYI/23#/Admin).  I also disabled html5 or I don't think it works with jsbin.

```
<div ng-view></div>
<p>Your user name is: {{ username }}</p>
<p>params.username is: {{ params.username }}</p>
<p>eventusername is: {{ eventusername }}</p>
<p>JSON:</p><pre>{{ params|json }}</pre>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.params = $routeParams;
```

Another option would be to look for route change events and handle them:

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
  $scope.eventusername = next.params.username;
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Follow-up question though: why do I need to use empty `ng-view` even though I don't render any view? Do you know why are those (routing and ngView) so closely coupled? Is there a way I could stick with clean markup (get rid of ng-view, since I don't actually need it here)?

Comment: No clue why it's necessary, I just remembered seeing it somewhere.  They're meant to work closely, normally you'd be creating a single page app and displaying different content in the view depending on the route.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're always using the `'ExampleCtrl'` controller, you're only ever reading the `$routeParams` once.  The `$routeParams` object is only created the one time that the controller is created.  It doesn't update dynamically.  So even though your route may have changed from say `/macadamia` to `/macadamia123`, the `$routeParams` object is still the same as it was when the controller was created for your `/macadamia` route (so `$routeParams.username` still equals `'/macadamia'`).  You need to reload the controller in order to read the `$routeParams` again.

I've wanted the `$routeParams` object to be dynamic for a long time, but unfortunately angular's `$routeProvider` doesn't work that way.